# Unable to start event gateway instance: Event Gateway Service is not enabled

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml, event-gateway

I recently migrated our server from ColdFusion 7 Enterprise to ColdFusion 10 Standard and now our event gateways aren't working. When I try to start them, it says:

> Unable to start event gateway instance: Event Gateway Service is not
>   enabled.

I do have "Enable ColdFusion Event Gateway Services" checked in the "Gateway Settings" page. When I turn the setting on and off, it says "Event Gateway Started.". Yet it still won't start my services. When I click start, I get the "Unable to start..." error.

I've seen a few posts about this problem, on Adobe's site, but no solutions. Both threads end with a comment that "it's working now!", but do not explain *how* the problem was fixed.

- [Unable to start event gateway instance: Event Gateway Service is not enabled., (service IS enabled)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aTCYzUodUbcMJ%3aforums.adobe.com/thread/1143757?tstart=0%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a)
- [Event Gateway Service/Instance Not Working](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/204629)

Am I totally forgetting a setting on the server or something?

Comment: Here are some of the people having the same problem but they don't say how they fixed it - [link]http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TCYzUodUbcMJ:forums.adobe.com/thread/1143757%3Ftstart%3D0+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a


[link]http://forums.adobe.com/thread/204629

Comment: "Enable ColdFusion Event Gateway Services now disabled by default" http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2012/3/7/charlie_areharts_ultimate_cf10_new_features_list

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. If you are using Standard and not Enterprise you will have to make sure you are only entering 1 in the thread. I was entering 8 like on our old server. When I was clicking update it was not really updating even though it said it was. After I updated it with 1 thread and restarted the server. It worked. I didn't even have to click start services, they came up on their own. I'm assuming since the answer was so simple why no one updated their own answer on the adobe forums, which was super annoying.

[image: Service will work on standard edition only if 1 thread is selected.]

[image: Only 1 Thread allowed Standard Edition]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting what worked for you. Hopefully this will help others in the future.

Comment: Nice detective work. You might consider [filing a bug report](https://bugbase.adobe.com/) as well. The Admin screen should at least mention the limitation and/or validate the value based on the server version instead of just failing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start the Event Gateway Service in CF Administrator, and then will likely need to restart ColdFusion service.

Comment: It is enabled. Also I did restart. Still says it's diabled on the services page, but it says it's enabled on the settings page.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by the insufficient privileges for the the directories you're trying to watch.
Check the service account of the Coldfusion Application Server service and see if it has sufficient privileges (i.e. local system account might not have access to the directories you're trying to watch)